# What's up with the shading?

Tags: modeling, edges

My shading on my chinook is really bugging me. I have put an edge split modifier on my model and this has elimated the majority of my issue but it still persists. As far as I can see, there are no existing ngons.

[image: Shading]

[image: Shading wireframe]

[image: 3.]

I want the beveled edges to have no shading issues. It should all be beveled. no sharp edges (anything that looks irregular is not what i want)

Comment: Could you indicate where you want your edges to be sharp, and where you want them rounded?

Comment: Added screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Are you subdividing? If so, this sort of topology works...

[image]

Comment: I'm avoiding subdivision, I don't want polycounts to be too high. That does work though. I'm still looking into it.   It looks fine when rendering. It's just object/edit view,

Comment: That's funny, I thought lo-poly shading by OpenGL was pretty indicative.. you've got me looking, now..